# ¿Es correcto decir "fichas rojas, naranjas y café"?

Tags: gramática, plurales, redacción, concordancia-gramatical, colores

Tengo un problema "de oído" al redactar un texto en el que se explica la función de los colores de las solapas de unas carpetas. En realidad puedo cambiar la redacción del texto y así evito el problema, pero me pareció interesante presentarlo aquí para averiguar si es una exageración, un error o a lo mejor una ambigüedad.

Me consta que hay que mantener la concordancia del plural, pero a veces me suena mal. Por ejemplo:

> Compré unos **vestidos rojos**. (Suena bien)
>
> Compré unos **zapatos cafés**.  (Suena mal)

Particularmente con el color café me es difícil aceptar la -s final del plural. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta?:

> ...las fichas rojas, naranjas y cafés
>
> o
>
> ...las fichas rojas, naranjas y café

Comment: La frase que dices que suena mal, a mi no me suena mal. Lo correcto es usar los plurales como lo señala la respuesta de @Pasaba por aquí

Comment: @DGaleano: la respuesta de fedorqui explica por qué a ti no te suena raro y a mí sí. En todo caso, gracias por hacerme notar que la forma en que planteo la pregunta es bastante subjetiva.

Comment: Después de leer la respuesta de @pasaba por aqui, puedo notar que lo que se aplica al color **café** también debe aplicarse al color **naranja**, porque ambos se refieren a objetos que tienen ese color característico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resumen para los que tengan prisa: en la mayor parte de América, se usaría el plural: *unas fichas cafés*; en España y otros lugares donde "café" no se entiende como sinónimo de "marrón", se usaría la forma singular: *unas fichas [de color] café*.

---

¡Interesante pregunta! He estado buscando y es una duda que más gente ha manifestado en otros foros (qué grande es internet, nunca puede uno ser el primero en nada :D).

El DRAE menciona como séptima acepción

> **[café](http://dle.rae.es/?w=caf%C3%A9&o=h)**
>
> Del it. caffe, este del turco kahve, y este del ár. clás. qahwah.
>
> 7. adj. marrón2. *Tonos café*. Apl. a color, u. t. c. s. m. U. m. en Am.

En este caso hay muchas iniciales, por lo que reescribo expandiéndolas todas:

> 7. adjetivo. marrón2. *Tonos café*. Aplicado a color, usado también como sustantivo masculino. Usado más en América.

Esta mención a América [la veo más restringida](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=37447) a unos cuantos países: Chile, Ecuador, México, Uruguay y El Salvador. Por tanto, "café" se usa como sinónimo de "marrón" en estos países. En el resto de países (en España por ejemplo) se dice "de color café", usando café como sustantivo.

Es precisamente esta elisión de la parte "de color" la que hace que ambas versiones puedan ser correctas:

- unas fichas [de color] café
- unas fichas cafés

Esta explicación resulta coherente y la baso en lo comentado en lo leído en el [foro del Instituto Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=39065), entrada 156067, que dice

> El uso puede sancionarlo todo.
>
> La elisión () "(de color) mostaza" hace que vaya en singular. Pero el
>   uso puede llevar al oyente a hacer la concordancia sin pensar en la
>   elisión. A mí me suena mal
>   *zapatos cafés*, bien *zapatos café*. Si no hay nada recogido en la
>   normativa, OLE, al respecto, debería recogerse. Cuando el hablante
>   pierde la sustentación del porqué o el mantenimiento de la forma que
>   ha recibido, actúa otra serie de reglas que poseemos, esto es, la
>   concordancia, pero ésta, en este caso, personalmente creo que no
>   debería darse, podríamos perder el norte al no dejar una marca
>   significativa, la no concordancia, del porqué café, por metonimia,
>   tiene remite a un color preciso. Ahora bien, cuando no hay indicación
>   contraria o motivo suficiente o conocido, como he dicho, el hablante
>   emplea otras normas al no prevalecer la razón dada, y por uso, si se
>   generaliza, licita *zapatos cafés*. Pero atendiendo a la semántica, nos
>   referimos al color de café, pero no de cafés, pues entonces
>   perderíamos el referente. Llegado a este punto, a qué café nos
>   referimos: No al que se encuentra en el campo, que hay de varios
>   colores, si no al que comúnmente conocemos, al grano tostado, o bien a
>   la infusión hecha con él: cafés
>
> En consecuencia, correcto es *zapatos (de color ) café*.

No sé cuánto hace que "café" se utiliza como sinónimo de "marrón". Supongo que a medida que este adjetivo sea más y más presente, se hará más fuerte su presencia "directa" (*unas fichas cafés*) y dejará de tener implícito el fragmento "de color" (*unas fichas café*).

Answer (score 7):

La [RAE, sobre "colores"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=O2YJVDPNGD6RHMUmU0):

> Cuando funcionan como adjetivos, hay que distinguir entre los nombres
>   que designan únicamente colores, los cuales concuerdan siempre con el
>   sustantivo al que modifican (faldas rojas, pantalones verdes, ojos
>   azules, etc.), y los nombres que designan primariamente una flor, un
>   fruto, una sustancia o un objeto que tienen ese color característico,
>   los cuales pueden usarse en aposición y permanecer invariables en
>   plural (ojos malva, faldas naranja, camisas añil, etc.) o concordar
>   con el sustantivo, con funcionamiento plenamente adjetivo (ojos
>   malvas, faldas naranjas, camisas añiles, etc.). Si, para designar
>   matices, un nombre de color se halla a su vez modificado por otro, o
>   por un adjetivo como claro, oscuro o similares, lo normal es mantener
>   ambos elementos invariables en singular, de acuerdo con el uso
>   mayoritario (pantalones verde botella, ojos azul claro, etc.)

En cualquier forma, en ocasiones puede ser conveniente el uso de la palabra "color". Por ejemplo:

> Juan cogió los vasos verdes y plátanos

resulta más legible como:

> Juan cogió los vasos color verde y color plátano

Comment: Esta respuesta es totalmente correcta y debería marcarla como aceptada, pero voy a preferir la de fedorqui porque deja clara la diferencia regional, que en este caso es bastante importante.