# ¿En qué países se usa "oso café" frente a "oso pardo"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, adjetivos

A mi hijo le sigue [apasionando](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20093/5481) la historia "[Brown bear, brown bear, what do you see?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Bear,_Brown_Bear,_What_Do_You_See%3F)" de Eric Carle. Tiene una copia del libro original en inglés y otra en [español](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805069011) (Oso Pardo, oso pardo, ¿qué ves ahí?).

A veces se lo pongo en video, y curiosamente hay tanto "[Oso pardo, oso pardo...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmKl9on5Jfo)" como "[Oso café, oso café](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3pdqG0XDbg)...". Él a veces me lo pide como "oso pardo" y otras como "oso café", a pesar de que ni yo (nativo de español de España) ni mi mujer (que habla español como segundo idioma) usamos nunca esta última denominación. Quizá algún día que haya estado viendo videos con la niñera, que es de Colombia, ella haya buscado el video como "Oso café" o leído la historia como tal.

No he tenido oportunidad de confirmar con ella si en Colombia se dice "oso café" o no (ella viene una vez por semana unas pocas horas, y es siempre mientras yo estoy fuera trabajando) o si se usa en otros países de Hispanoamérica.

Así pues, lanzo aquí mi pregunta, ¿en qué países se usa "Oso café" en lugar de "Oso Pardo"?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Es correcto decir “fichas rojas, naranjas y café”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15311/1674)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Igual aquí hace falta una respuesta de tipo *community wiki*, pero de momento en el *Diccionario de americanismos* de la ASALE podemos ver:

> **[café](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=caf%C3%A9)**.
>   I.  1.  adj. *Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, Cu, RD, Co, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar, Ur.* De color café.
>      2.    adj/sust. *Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, Cu, RD, Co, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar, Ur, Referido a color*, similar al del grano de café tostado.

Así pues, se podría decir que usar la palabra *café* para referirse al color es propio de México, Guatemala, Honduras, El Salvador, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Panamá, Cuba, República Dominicana, Colombia, Ecuador, Perú, Bolivia, Chile, Paraguay, Argentina y Uruguay. Otra cosa ya es que la expresión *oso café* sea más usada que *oso pardo* en dichos países. Nótese que Colombia, país de origen de tu niñera, está en la lista.

Es interesante mencionar también que la palabra *[pardo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pardo)* significa, referida a persona, "de tez oscura y rasgos aindiados" en países como Bolivia y Argentina. También en Bolivia y además en Uruguay dice que es una palabra despectiva para referirse a los mulatos.

Answer (score 1):

"Oso café" es una mala traducción.  *(Comentario editorial: La biblioteca donde yo vivo tiene varios estantes llenos de libros infantiles mal traducidos al español.)*

Fuente: http://www.osopedia.com/tipos-osos/

Este artículo tiene una lista de especies de osos, incluyendo el *oso pardo*; no hay mención del *oso café*.

Busqué asiduosamente algún artículo científico sobre osos, que tuviera mención del oso café, y sólo encontré [uno](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1523-1739.1998.96351.x/abstract).  Para mostrar la calidad de traducción de este artículo:

> La distribución histórica del oso café en Norte **América** **incluída** (tales lugares).

Aparte de este artículo, la búsqueda `"oso café" -Carle` solo me dio osos de peluche.

Además, *oso café* no se oye bien.  *Oso pardo* se oye mucho mejor.

Comment: Que en algunos países, como España, se llame *oso pardo* ya lo sabemos, lo dice la propia pregunta. Eso no significa que llamarlo *oso café* sea incorrecto.

Comment: @Gorpik - amplié mi respuesta.

Comment: Coincido. Tan raro me sonaba a mi también que incluso aporté vídeo con "oso café". En cualquier caso, si la gente en ciertos países usa "café" para ese color, normal que acaben diciendo "oso café"...

Comment: @diego - Leí http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15311/1674, y no estoy muy de acuerdo con la conclusión.  Me parece que en México es mejor decir *castaño* que *café*. // Pero hay cosas peores en la literatura infantil de traducción.