# ¿Cómo se llama al sonido que hace un flamenco?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

*Polar Bear, Polar Bear, What Do You Hear?* de Bill Martin Jr y Eric Carle es todavía uno de los libros favoritos de mi hijo. A diferencia de otros de sus libros favoritos (como [*Brown Bear, Brown Bear, What Do You See?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20161/5481)) de este tenemos solo copia en inglés por lo que a veces, para exponerle más al idioma, intento leérselo en español traduciendo "al vuelo".

Siempre me atasco con "I hear a flamingo *[fluting](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=fluting)* in my ear". Entiendo que es un graznido tipo flauta, pero no sé cuál sería el término más correcto para describir en español el sonido que hacen los flamencos.

Es decir, un [graznido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JW0fZYL) es

> Grito de algunas aves, como el cuervo, el grajo, el ganso, etc.

¿Entra el flamenco en esa categoría? Para equinos distinguimos entre un relincho y un rebuzno. ¿Quizá hay una palabra especial para definir ese graznido *aflautado* característico de los flamencos?

Comment: Seguramente los autores escogieron "fluting" porque empieza con F.  "They are known to converse in goose-like honking or squawking" (http://www.bioexpedition.com/chilean-flamingo/). // Sobre todo con los libros de poco texto, como éste, sí, es mucho mejor traducir el texto uno mismo, como dices, que aguantar la mala traducción de la casa editorial.  "Oso polar, oso polar / Señor León, Señor León / etc. / ¿Qué oyes tú? / ¿Cuál es ese sonido?"  (¿Qué es ese ruido? Ay de mí.) // Para mí, el sonido interesante del flamenco se produce cuando el grupo emprende vuelo, batiendo las alas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmm no sé si alguna vez habéis oído [el sonido de un flamenco](https://youtu.be/-flPDGARXp0), pero de "aflautado" tiene poco. Estoy con lo indicado por @aparente001 en los comentarios: seguramente los autores usan *fluting* porque empieza por F igual que *flamingo*, nada más.

Creo que **graznido** está bien como traducción libre.
Y si realmente quieres transmitir el concepto de flauta aunque no sea lo real para un flamenco, entonces **silbido** sería otra opción.

Answer (score 2):

Si el grito del ganso es un **graznido**, posiblemente el del flamenco también lo sea. En todo caso, si lo que quería el autor era realmente hacer coincidir en sonido *fl-* de *flamenco* y *fluting*, podemos intentar hacer lo mismo

Según el DLE:

> **[flauteado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I3ti1JI)**
>
> 1. adj. Dicho especialmente de la voz dulce y delicada: De sonido semejante al de la flauta.

Dado que este adjetivo tiene la forma de un participio, pensé que igual existía la voz *flautear*. Buscando en el NTLLE, veo que esta voz nunca ha aparecido en ninguna de las ediciones del DLE, mas sí que aparece en otros diccionarios, como el Domínguez (1853), el Zerolo (1895) y el Alemany y Bolufer (1917). De ellos se desprende que el verbo *flautear* significa "tocar la flauta, ejecutar un flauteado".

Por tanto, si quieres tomarte una licencia poética en este caso, puedes decir que "**el flamenco flauteaba**".

Comment: ¿Puedes proponer algo para lo que se oye cuando el grupo emprende vuelo, batiendo las alas?